# How to fetch child names in Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my `Firebase` database. I want to fetch only the child names of `Intake-Sec` like `CSE, EEE`. Not the children of `CSE` or `EEE`. How can I do this?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: with realtime-database, you always fetch the whole subtree. it's bad if you have a very big subtree (slow + network cost). so just create a new child under `Intake-Sec` named `departments` and under it add `CSE` and `EEE` only. This is normalization

Comment: What I want to do is get those departments name and use them for drop down items. I can get those names in linked list and when I set them to my drop down it only shows the items on click. And when I select an item it does not show the selected item in the drop down bar. With array it works fine. But the problem is when I try "String[] arr = linkedlist.toArray(new String[linkedlist.size()]" it shows that the linked list is empty.

Comment: try `String[] arr = new String[linkedlist.size()]; arr = linkedlist.toArray(arr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the `CSE` and `EEE`, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            list.add(key);
            Log.d(TAG, key);
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your list
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The list will contains only two elements as it will also be printed in the logcat:

```
CSE
EEE
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I toast list it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I'm positive! Please add to your question the code that you are using. There for sure something wrong.

Comment: What I want to do is get those departments name and use them for drop down items. Linked list stores those name and when I set that list to my drop down it only shows the items on click. And when I select an item it does not show the selected item in the drop down bar. With array items it works fine. But the problem is when I try "String[] arr = linkedlist.toArray(new String[linkedlist.size()]" it shows that the linked list is empty.

Comment: This sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Ok. I will post a new question in few minutes with required code and info and I will comment you the question link in here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049334/linked-list-shows-nothing-after-fetching-data-from-firebase-to-the-linked-list

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.