# Linked list is empty after fetching data from Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, linked-list

[image]

I fetch these department names (CSE, EEE) from `firebase` to a `linked list` and set that `linked list` as items of my `drop down`. When I click the drop down it shows the items but when I select an item it does not appears as selected item on the drop down bar.

If I use `array` then the drop down works fine. But the problem is when I try to convert the `linked list` into an `array` using `String[] arr = linkedlist.toArray(new String[linkedlist.size()]` it shows that the `linked list` is empty.

**Normal drop down:**

[image]

**After clicking drop down:**

[image]

**After selecting an item:**

[image]

**Java Class:**

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = null;
    private Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;
    private Button next;

    LinkedList<String> deptlist = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_dept);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_int);
        sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_sec);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Intake-Sec");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = ds.getKey();
                    deptlist.add(key);
                    Log.d(TAG, key);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

        /*does not work. deptlist.size() returns 0 item

        String[] deptarr = deptlist.toArray(new String[deptlist.size()]);

        */

        ArrayAdapter ar = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,deptlist);
        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        sp1.setAdapter(ar);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can take a look a **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171376/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-and-show-in-android-studio/53171680)**.

Comment: Yes! It works now! Using the "ArrayAdapter<String> adapter" it solved the problem. I was struggling my whole day to solve this. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help.

Comment: ok I have given you the vote-up.